# Replace special characters in string when copied from Microsoft word(for Classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to figure out an issue in my Classic ASP application, whenever a user tries to copy text from Microsoft word into Textarea placeholder & save, it is stored in the Database as a??.

I tried replacing special character like single quote using following statement

1. `Replace(Trim(Request.Form("Description")),chr(39), "'")`
2. `Replace(Trim(Request.Form("Description")),chr(39), "'")`

Both the above statements didn't work. It was able to find special character-single quote when I type in & replaced it with ' when I use 2nd statement but for some weird reason it doesn't still work for Copy paste from Microsoft word.

Comment: Your two statements look identical.  Did you past the incorrect one for the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Because word uses character 145 rather than 39,

So your code should be

```
Replace(Trim(Request.Form("Description")),chr(145), "'")
```

Comment: For some strange reason, i am still having problem even after using Chr(145)

Comment: Then it possibly is another character yet again.  So you will have to debug and find out what the actual character is